# Post image file to database from esp8266

Tags: tcp, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I want to post image files of size around 15Kb, form my esp8266 based prototype to a non-sql database . I could post the json files of size less than 1Kb, But the http post fails for size grater than 1460 bytes.

```
HTTPClient http;
if( http.begin(myurl) ){
   delay(1000);
   char *auth = authString;
   http.setAuthorization(auth);

   http.addHeader("Content-Type","application/json",  false, true);
   int err = http.POST(largedata);
   Serial1.print("HTTP Post reutrns : ");Serial1.println(err);
}
```

Comment: out of ram. remove unused components. there might be an upload stream interface to use if you have/can put the data in SPIFFS.

Comment: Yeah.. SPIFFS is a good feature. But I am looking for a iot soution. Probably i need post as "multipart/form-data" data

Comment: SPIFFS is the filesytem on the ESP8266 arduino firmware, how is that not IoT?